# Execute MySql in PHP from terminal (bash)

Tags: php, mysql, bash

I have this problem, i have created a php file which inserts data into a mysqldatabase on Mamp.

I can use the command mysql anywhere and it starts the mysql client.

But when i start my php script i get this error:

```
Warning: Error establishing mySQL database connection. Correct user/password? Correct hostname? Database server running? in
```

For testing i have used the default username and password "root". Anyone know what causes this?

I have also tried this command:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: Really hard to tell without knowing what your database connection code looks like.

Comment: Have you tried using the mysql php libraries for connecting to mysql? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

For me it is working fine. Which hostname you are using in your `php` code?

```
sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ cat con_mysql.php 
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","root","PASSWORD");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
else
    {
    echo "Connection Established\n"; 
    }
mysql_close($con);
?>

sgeorge-mn:~ sgeorge$ php con_mysql.php 
Connection Established
```

Comment: I use ezSQL for database handling and i use "localhost" when trying to connect. Edit: Will try your code and see if it works :)

Comment: Are you sure you have entry for `localhost` in `etc/hosts` file. Can you try with `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`.